# Pass additional variables to a function variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using a function in TensorFlow which maps a set of tensors to another arrangement of tensors. For example, you might write:

```
data = data.map(_function)

def _function(a, b, c):
    return (a + 1, b, c)
```

So here, you pass _function as a function variable to map, and map passes it three tensors, which are mutated in some way (here, just adding one) and returned.

---

**My question is**: Is there a way to pass in additional variables to _function?

If I want to perform `a + x`, and not `a + 1`, then how could I pass in the additional variable?

You can't do something like: `data.map(_function(x))` because then you're passing the result of a function, not the function itself.

I've experimented with *arg, but I can't find a way. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do sth like

```
def extra_func(x):
    def _function(a, b, c):
        return (a + x, b, c)
    return _function
```

So you can do `data.map(extra_func(x))`

or you can use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to fix some of a function params

Comment: Except now in this case, `_extra_func()` is being passed `a, b, c` by the `.map()` function.

Comment: I can't get your first method to fix my specific problem, but I can fix it with functools.partial to add further parameters to the function. Thanks so much for that helping hand.

Comment: From your question I understand that the map parameter needs to take a 3 parameter function. `extra_func(10)` returns a 3 parameter function that has the x fixed to 10.

Comment: Oh snap it does. Yeah, you're right, that would also fix it.